# Vuejs: Show confirmation dialog before route change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

In my vueJS project, I want to show confirmation dialog before the current route changes.
[image]

On yes, it should redirect to next desired route otherwise keep it on same route.

Any idea how to achieve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use **In-Component Guards** `beforeRouteLeave`. See https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html .

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/jzr5nojn39 (try navigating between home, page 1, page 2)

Sample Code (using [vuejs-dialog](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-dialog) as the confirmation dialog):

```
    beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) {
        this.$dialog.confirm('Do you want to proceed?')
        .then(function () {
            next();
        })
        .catch(function () {
            next(false);
        });
    }
```

If it should proceed, use `next()`.

If the redirection should be cancelled, use `next(false)`.

Comment: Is it possible to implement it as a mixin ?

Comment: @lbris the answer is yes

Comment: Fine I'll work on that in my new project. Better if I can call it in any component in 1 line thanks to the mixin mechanism.

Answer (score 15):

> The accepted answer shows how to do it by using [vuejs-dialog](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-dialog). But if you don't want to use this library check below:

**Say you have a dialog with 3 options:**

**close dialog** => calls `closeDialog()` and stays in the same page

**save changes** => calls `saveChanges()` save changes and navigates away

**discard changes** => calls `discardChanges()`navigates away without saving changes

```
  data: () => ({
    to: null,
    showDialog: false
  }),

  beforeRouteLeave(to, from, next) {
    if (this.to) {
      next();
    } else {
      this.to = to;
      this.showDialog = true;
    }
  },

  methods: {
    closeDialog() {
      this.showDialog = false;
      this.to = null;
    },

    saveChanges() {
      // add code to save changes here
      this.showDialog = false;
      this.$router.push(this.to);
    },

    discardChanges() {
      this.showDialog = false;
      this.$router.push(this.to);
    }
  }
```

[See it in action in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-router-show-dialog-before-route-change-rvhow)

**Takeaway** The key takeaway here is the [beforeRouteLeave](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards) navigation guard, where we don't allow the user to navigate away if the `to` property in data is null. The only case it cannot be null is when the user clicks save or discard button in the dialog.

Comment: if you had to check save button is enabled how should it be? 

if ( this.saveEnabled && this.to ) next (). ¿?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

VueJS has **In Component Navigation Guards** like `beforeRouteUpdate` and `beforeRouteLeave`

```
beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
  // called before the route that renders this component is confirmed.
  // does NOT have access to `this` component instance,
  // because it has not been created yet when this guard is called!
},
...
beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) {
  // called when the route that renders this component is about to
  // be navigated away from.
  // has access to `this` component instance.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The following code works for me

```
 <v-btn @click="deleteDialog = true">Delete</v-btn>
      <v-dialog v-model="deleteDialog" max-width="500px">
       <v-card>
               <v-card-title style="font-size:20px" >Are you sure you want to archive?</v-card-title>
               <v-card-actions>
                   <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                   <v-btn color="red" style="font-size:15px" flat @click.native="deleteDialog = false">No</v-btn>
                   <v-btn color="green" style="font-size:15px" flat @click.native="deleteItem">Yes</v-btn>
               </v-card-actions>
           </v-card>
       </v-dialog>
```