# VueJS / Nuxt - display popup if navigation guard condition

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am currently trying to achieve displaying a popup when switching pages if a draft needs to be saved.

I set up a plugin with a navigation guard checking for the draft to exist but cannot figure out how to trigger the popup display.

`plugins/routeGuard.js`

```
export default function ({ app, store }) {

    app.router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
        if (store.state.draft.id) {
            console.log("draft")
            // display popup asking to save draft
            next();
        } else {
            console.log("no draft")
            next();
       }
   });
}
```

`import draft_save_popup  from '~/components/draft/popup/save';`

nuxt.config.js

```
plugins             : [
    '~/plugins/routeGuard.js',
],
```

I have no idea how to invoke the `draft_save_popup` now that the guard is set up..

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vuejs: Show confirmation dialog before route change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50094129/vuejs-show-confirmation-dialog-before-route-change)

Answer (score 1):

You can import **draft_save_popup** component to your layout and then show it with **v-if** only when variable **displayPopup** is true. You can save that variable in the vuex store or wherever you want and then change its value in this plugin, which will make the condition true and popup will show up.